# Find the fewest turning path

Tags: path-finding

```
Tiles = {  
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},  
{0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0},  
{0,3,0,0,2,4,2,2,2,0},  
{0,0,2,0,0,0,2,2,2,0},  
{0,0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,0},  
{0,0,0,0,2,0,2,2,2,0},  
{0,0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,0},  
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}  
}
```

0 is not clickable, other is clickable, otherways 0 is walkable an other is not, weh i click Tiles[3][2] (number 3) then Tiles[3][6] (number 4), i want to connect that 2 tile through walkable tile, the problem is i dont need a shortest solution, instead i need solution that have 2 or less corner (turning), i have spent 3 days to imagine and googling the algorithm, but no luck, can someone give me a clue or article about that, and i use lua but other language is still i appreciate.

Comment: What is your question? And what's up with the second paragraph - is it part of your question?

Comment: sory, second paragraf is answer i get when i ask in yahoo, i forgot that.

Comment: i try to conenct two tile with equeal or less than 2 turning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your grid into a graph using the following rules:

- Every walkable tile in the grid corresponds to a node in the graph.
- Two nodes are connected (with weight 1) in the graph if they are in the same row or column in the grid and every tile between them in the grid is walkable.

The shortest path in the graph corresponds to the path with fewest corners in the grid.

Comment: then check to make sure it satisfies the 2 or less constraint

Comment: But how do i transform grid into a graph, can you give me a sample.